# Projector responsiveness using media query

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, responsive-design

So I designed a website for my department, it is very responsive on my system and other mobile devices I previewed it on. However, when I tried to demo it using a projector, some of the elements like the navbar were out of place.

Is there any media query to target projector screen size? Something like @media projection

Thanks in anticipation of your quick response

Comment: You could target the projector based on its resolution or pixel-ratio. There's no specific 'projector' setting

Comment: can you share some code to reproduce the behavior?

Answer (score 0):

use max-width on the media query to maintain it width.